# Vocals sound 'dead' in recording

Tags: voice, homerecording

I recorded some vocals in a quiet room in my home using a tripod mounted Zoom H1 recorder. However, the resulting sound seems dead and dry, and seems to lack any "atmosphere". What changes to the recording environment (the room, mic position, etc) can I modify to fix this?

Comment: Probably would need to hear the sound to offer good suggestions, can you link to it?

Comment: what do you mean by "dead" and "atmosphere"?

Comment: I realize these are subjective terms - but dead in the sense of totally lacking reverb. By atmosphere I am referring to the characteristics of the room: to oversimplify it seems the recording has absolutely no reverb. Hope that helps. Unfortunately I don't have a recording I can share at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the recording environment, so much as the production. In my home studio days (long gone) a bit of reverb and compression would work wonders on vocals.

Comment: If you really have a 'dead' recording you're lucky! Run it through an audio sequencer and add a bit of delay, echo... the usual tricks recording engineers use to tart up a dry recording. The problem with home recording is more often that you CAN hear the room, in a nasty 'boxy' way. That's harder to correct. This question all hinges on just WHAT problem your recording has. Can you post it somewhere and give us a link? Otherwise we're just guessing really, and relying too much on what may be a loose description.

Comment: as said above, you should probably link the recording.  But experiment with mic placement to see what changes, and also set up recording in a few different rooms, to see if it really is the room that's causing the problem or not.  Be a scientist ;)

Comment: @peterG I'm guessing it was the environment because a different venue with all the same equipment did not yield the same result. The original recording cannot be shared unfortunately, but I will experiment with new recordings over the weekend and post my results.

Comment: Unfortunately the original recording is not shareable, and I realise that answering this q without it is difficult. Both answers have excellent suggestions though; so I'll try and experiment and post back my results.

Comment: Can't share or won't share?   If the former, we can find a way.

Comment: Can't share the original recording because I recorded it specifically for someone else - but I can do another with similar vocals, and the same recording hardware (which I own), with variations in the mic position and the use of curtains/blankets etc.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea with recording is to make a dry(ish) sound. Towards the end, after mixing, effects are put onto tracks, particularly vocals and reverb. I'm guessing the Zoom has no such facilities, so either use a reverb pedal, or brighten up the room. This can be done with lack of carpet, curtains and soft furnishings. Putting the recorder by a window (closed!) may give some slight echo effect, experimentation will be the menu of the day.You could try the recorder in a corner, which may give a slight echo effect as well, depending where the vocalist is situated. If you can sing through a mic/amp. with reverb, it'll help too.